# Parse url query parameters in C glib?

Tags: c, parsing, url, glib

Is it possible to get URL fragment parameters in C under glib ?

I've got a url like `file://localhost/home/me/notepad.txt#line=100,2`

What's the best way to get the parameters specified at the end of the url ?

Comment: The [relevant section](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.60/glib-URI-Functions.html) of the GLib documentation suggests not; at least not in a handy do-it-for-you function.

Comment: Cheers, I guess they just implemented what they needed - seemed a bit weird there was nothing there.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no single GLib function which will do what you want. If you can use libsoup (also part of the GNOME stack), then you can do it using [`SoupURI`](https://developer.gnome.org/libsoup/stable/SoupURI.html):

```
g_autoptr(SoupURI) uri = soup_uri_new (uri_string);
const gchar *fragment = soup_uri_get_fragment (uri);
```

That will set `fragment` to `line=100,2`. You’ll have to do further parsing of whatever your fragment format is, by hand. [`g_strsplit()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html#g-strsplit) would be useful for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may also take a look on the function [parse_sftp_uri](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/master/src/terminal-nautilus.c#L141) from gnome-terminal  terminal-nautilus.c file.
It can be easily adapted for general URIs.

Answer (score -1):

Unsure if you mean to parse *notepad.txt#line=100,2* or *#line=100,2*, nevertheless my answer should work in both cases.

You can use the `strrchr()` (man strrchr) function to get the last occurence of a character within a string.

Something like:

```
char *file;
file = strrchr(url, '/') + 1;
```

Comment: That won’t work if the fragment itself contains a `/`.

Comment: I believe there can't be a '/' in a URL or else it's not the parameter

Comment: [RFC 3986](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.5) explicitly allows `/` (and `?`) in fragments. The syntax for a fragment is `fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )`.

Comment: That's a bit surprising to say the least, I was doing SEO and had to parse millions of URLs for analysis purposes and can't recall ever having this issue. Guess I was just lucky :) thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Hi, it's the `line=100,2` I'd like to extract.

Comment: My solution above isn't working properly with '/' character as mentioned by Philipp Withnall but should do the job with '#' character hopefully then!

Comment: Yes, `strrchr()` with `#` should work, as the `pchar` generation which forms the bulk of `fragment` [cannot contain literal `#` characters](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-50). (They have to be percent-encoded.)